# Enabling triple slash auto-complete in visual studio for c++?

Tags: visual-studio

When I type three slashes in a c# project in visual studio community 2017, then a placeholder for documentation appears, e.g.:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ppcode"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public double multForType(int ppcode)
        { 
           //Implementation goes here. 
        }
```

This somehow does not work for a c++ project. Is there a way to get this, or similar functionality, to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a downloadable extention: [CppTripleSlash - xml doc comments for c++](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tcbhat.CppTripleSlash-xmldoccommentsforc)

Comment: This works great and out of the box, also for visual studio community 2017.